# How to disable DisplayInfo for Intel i810 when there is no xorg.conf?

Tags: graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, intel, xserver

I'm testing 12.04 on an office desktop. This machine has an integrated Intel i810. This very machine used to run Ubuntu (or Kubuntu) quite well, until the Natty Narwhal release, when the X server started freezing.

This seems to be caused by an issue with a call to the video BIOS, which can be circumvented by disabling the option DisplayInfo.

I tried creating an `xorg.conf` by using `Xorg -configure`, but it produced an error after trying to make a file. I did have a file, and I put it in `/etc/X11` with `DisplayInfo false` (maybe it wants "disabled"?), but it wouldn't boot at all until I removed that `xorg.conf`.

There is no `10-monitor.conf` file either. All I want to do is set the appropriate option so that my Intel display doesn't freeze.

Is there any other way I can disable the DisplayInfo?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Xorg.conf with a command

```
Xorg -configure
```

Then after customizing it and copying to /etc/X11, probably will possible what you need.

The file will be saved as xorg.conf.new in your home directory. Important thing is that you have turn off your X first and generate the file from console level (not terminal window running under the X).